# Running Angular cli e2e tests in headless Chrome with travis ci

Tags: angular, google-chrome, protractor, angular-cli, travis-ci

I am trying to use Chrome's new headless browser mode to run angular tests on Travis ci but encounter an error when running my protractor e2e tests with `npm run e2e` (`ng e2e`). Running my units tests with `npm test` (`ng test --watch=false`) works fine though.

Travis Config:

```yaml
sudo: false
dist: trusty

language: node_js
node_js:
  - '6.11'

addons:
  chrome: stable

install:
  - npm install -g @angular/cli
  - npm install

script:
  - npm test
  - npm run e2e

notifications:
  webhooks:
    on_success: change
    on_failure: always
    on_start: false
```

Protractor Config:

```js
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=800x600']
    }
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

Travis Error

```
webpack: Compiled successfully.
[03:23:26] I/file_manager - creating folder /home/travis/build/kpfromer/smarttodo-angular/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium
[03:23:26] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.35.zip
[03:23:27] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /home/travis/build/kpfromer/smarttodo-angular/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.35
[03:23:27] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[03:23:27] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[03:24:27] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.14.12-041412-generic x86_64)
[03:24:27] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.14.12-041412-generic x86_64)
    at WebDriverError (/home/travis/build/kpfromer/smarttodo-angular/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/travis/build/kpfromer/smarttodo-angular/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/travis/build/kpfromer/smarttodo-angular/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/home/travis/build/kpfromer/smarttodo-angular/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
...
```

Answer (score 4):

It's an issue with **google chrome's sandbox mode** that is stopping chrome from creating a session.

You need to disable it.

Example protractor config:

```js
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=800,600', '--no-sandbox']
    }
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

See [a similar GitHub issue.](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/255)